# Exec Python code with nonlocals

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have three dictionaries `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to `exec()` a code snippet where `a` is the globals, `b` is the nonlocals and `c` is the locals. That is no problem for the globals and locals, as I just have to use `exec(code, a, c)` -- but what about `b`? How can I make the values in `b` visible to the code snippet as nonlocal variables?

I think this clarifies the concept:

```
assert globals() == a and locals() == a
def foo():
  assert globals() == a and locals() == b
  def bar():
    assert globals() == a and locals() == c
    exec(code)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this at all, what's the context? What are you `exec`uting? See also e.g. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-August/610136.html, https://bugs.python.org/issue16781.

Comment: The context is a custom DSL which can evaluate Python code snippets in nested scopes. From your links, it appears to be non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not exactly executing Python code with nonlocals, I was able to rewrite the AST so that it behaves the way I want. Every variable that is being accessed and that is not locally defined in a function or class scope is rewritten to access a mapping instead.

This is an example that demonstrates a possible use case where `a` is the dictionary that takes precedence over `b` and will receive all variable assignments, but the values of `b` are still taken into account if not shadowed by `a`.

```
from nr.datastructures.chaindict import ChainDict
from nr.ast.dynamic_eval import dynamic_exec

d1 = {'a': 42}
d2 = {'b': 'spam'}

code ='''
print(a, b) # prints 42 spam
a = 'egg'
b = 'ham'
'''

dynamic_exec(code, ChainDict(d1, d2))
assert d1 == {'a': 'egg', 'b': 'ham'}, d1
assert d2 == {'b': 'spam'}, d2
```

Available with [nr](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/py-nr) v2.0.4 *(disclaimer: I am the developer of that package)*.

---

*A little bit more detail*

The `dynamic_exec()` function will parse the Python code using `ast.parse()` and then apply an `ast.NodeTransformer` which rewrites global variable names.
Example:

```
import os
from os import path

parent_dir = path.dirname(__file__)

def main():
  filename = path.join(parent_dir, 'foo.py')
  print(filename)
```

This will be turned into an AST that is semantically equivalent to

```
import os; __dict__['os'] = os
from os import path; __dict__['path'] = path

__dict__['parent_dir'] = __dict__['path'].dirname(__dict__['__file__'])

def main():
  filename = __dict__['path'].join(__dict__['parent_dir'], 'foo.py')
  __dict__['print'](filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @jonrsharpe link, and to my tests, you can't. Unless you make what you call the nonlocals `b` available to the closure, at closure definition time (as a dict argument for example). At the time you use exec, the closure is already defined with cell values unchangeable.

Edit:

But if you send a mutable argument to the closure, such as a `dict`, you gain some flexibility, as now you can act on it almost like if you were acting on the closure cell values:

```
def func(b):
    def inner():
        b['count'] += 1 # nonlocal doesn't matter here
        return b['count']
    return inner

b = dict(count=100)
f1 = func(b)
exec('print(f1())') # locals don't matter
b['count'] = 200    # now a little change in the environment...
exec('print(f1())')
```

Comment: That give's me a idea of transforming the AST to access variables via a dictionary...